# gem - search Chinese with pg_search

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, rubygems

I am using [pg_search](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search). it's fine with English, but I cannot use it to search Chinese content. When I set Chinese as input:

```
NOTICE:  text-search query contains only stop words or doesn't contain lexemes, ignored
```

I can use ActiveRecord API `where` to search Chinese, so I think it's not a problem about my db setting.

How should I config pg_search to work with Chinese?

Comment: I think it's because Chinese requires corresponding dictionary: 
https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search#dictionary

Comment: I don't think this 'dictionary' is about different languages. It's about how to let pg distinguish thesaurus. :)